# If I register a custom signal handler on a process before forking, will the subsequent child processes also have the custom signal handler registered?

Tags: c, operating-system, signals, system-calls

When we call SIGINT (ctrl+c) on a parent process, I understand that the parent process will relay the signal to its child processes. However, will the child processes handle the signal in the same way as the parent, assuming that I have registered a custom signal handler before forking. For example:

```
void interruptHandler(int sig) {
    int thisPid = (int) getpid();
    while (1) {
        int childPid = wait(NULL);
        if (childPid == -1) break;
        printf("\t[%d] terminated.\n", childPid);
    }

    printf("PID[%d] Ended.\n", thisPid);
    exit(1);

}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    if (signal(SIGINT, interruptHandler) == SIG_ERR) {
        printf("Handler registration error");
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Executing ctrl+c when the above process is running seems to give me the impression that the parent only handles the signal with the custom handler, while the child process handle the signal with the default handler.

This is what the output looks like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovI1V.png)

Is there a way to get the child processes to use the custom handler?

Comment: This is false: "When we call SIGINT (ctrl+c) on a parent process, I understand that the parent process will relay the signal to its child processes". Rather, signals generated by actions on the controlling terminal are sent to the entire foreground process group, which includes both the parent and child unless they change their process groups.

Comment: The child is an almost exact copy of the parent and it’s signal handlers are unchanged.  If there’s an `execve()` or similar, signal handling changes, but not with `fork()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You're telling the child processes to exit *immediately*, so they never get a chance to get the signal.  Instead, have the children `break` out of the loop:

```
for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Then the child processes will be active when CTRL-C is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes: Your use of `stdio` is badly messed up with respect to both signals and forking. Unless (roughly speaking; the detailed rules can be found in the POSIX XSH 2.5.1) you flush the stream before forking, only one forked child can continue to use a given stream (in your case, `stdout`) after the fork. In general it's unsafe to call functions which are not classified as "async-signal safe" from a signal handler too, but as long as you've reached the while loop before you hit Ctrl-C that should not affect you.

With that said, your problem just seems to be that your child processes are immediately exiting:

```
if (pid == 0) {
        return 0;
}
```